# Executing a stored procedure over a linked server embedded as a synonym

Tags: sql-server

If I use a domain account with explicit execute permissions, I can successfully execute a stored procedure over a linked server using a four part name eg [LINKEDSERVER].Databasename.schema.ProcedureName

However, if that four part name is defined within a database synonym - the explicit execute permission isn't enough. Indeed, I haven't been able to be able to execute it at all. I've tried it with a variety of versions of SQL Server up to 2017.

In the Microsoft docs, there's a note about four part names for functions not being supported, but I didn't think a synonym is a function - it's an object.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/synonyms/synonyms-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017

I suspect it is one step too far, but are there any ways to make it work?

Comment: Are you executing `EXEC [LINKEDSERVER].DB.Schema.Synonym` or are you executing `EXEC [LINKEDSERVER].DB.Schema.Proc` which references a synonym, or are you executing `EXEC DB.Schema.Synonym` and the local synonym references a linked server procedure?

Comment: The latter - EXEC DB.Schema.Synonym